# Mulesoft custom policy validation using Postman

Tags: postman, mulesoft

Say you have a Mulesoft API which has a custom policy applied. The policy would encrypt a value (eg. accountId) of the response from the API. Is it possible to call this custom policy through a postman script where you'd send an accountId and get the encrypted value? How do you validate a custom policy in Mulesoft?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your API is a REST API the received JSON (or XML) you send to it an HTTP request and check that the answer is the expected one. You can't really test the policy directly. A policy modifies the input or output of an API. You need to apply it to an API and observe the results. Any HTTP client (postman, curl) or your preferred programming language should work as a client. That's the point of using HTTP.

Comment: Thanks @aled for the clarification. Makes sense now. I saw that the policy can be applied to a Mulesoft API through a postman request. Thought, there was a possibility of a similar method to access the policy itself.